# Как сделать join один ко многму и взять только одно поле?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица **users** и **user_phones** (*один ко многому*), как  получить список где каждый user имел бы только один номер ?

Использовал

```
SELECT users.*, 
       user_phones.number as phone_number 
  FROM users
  JOIN user_phones 
    ON users.id = user_phones.user_id;
```

но получаются повторения.

Comment: Использовать группировку или объединять с лимитированным подзапросом.

Comment: Если телефонов у юзера больше одного, то какой единственный нужно взять и почему? В ответе на вопрос кроется разгадка!